# Can't resolve 'babel-loader'

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, node-modules, webpack-2

I am trying to configure my first node react app.

I keep getting an error that says "Can't resolve babel-loader".

Googling that error, I found a couple of suggestions which do not work.

The first is to add the following to my webpack.config.js

```
// resolveLoader: {
  //       modulesDirectories: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
  //   },
```

Trying that produces an error that says:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolveLoader has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
```

The next suggestion is to try:

```
resolveLoader: {
        fallback: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
    },
```

That produces a similar error.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get started with this configuration. Understanding the documentation is proving difficult - every second word is jargon and I can't find a reference point to find fundamental understanding of what needs to be done to get started in this setup.

Webpack.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      Greeter: 'app/components/Greeter.jsx',
      GreeterMessage: 'app/components/GreeterMessage.jsx',
      GreeterForm: 'app/components/GreeterForm.jsx',

    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },

  // resolveLoader: {
  //       fallback: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
  //   },

  module :{
    rules:[{
      // use : 'babel-loader',
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query :{
        presets:['react','es2015']
        // ,'es2017'
      },
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }
   ]
 }


};
```

Comment: do you have installed `babel-loader` module?

Comment: and please show us `your webpack.config.js`

Comment: @chenkehxx - yes, babel-loader is in my dev dependencies

Comment: check what is the version of your webpack, it's `1.x` or `2.x`

Comment: web pack is with v2.6.1

Comment: Check and ensure `babel-loader` is installed in your `node_modules`.

Comment: @Mel did you find a soluion? I have the exact problem...and the answer of JESI does not help...

Answer (score 82):

I had the same problem; I fixed it by installing the babel-loader module:

`yarn add -D babel-loader`

or

`npm install --save babel-loader`

Comment: should  it be yarn add -D babel-loader? Any reason you'd need this in production?

Comment: Thanks, @JulianK -- I've fixed the answer!