# Circular errors about babel-loader when launching React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn dev` I get the error that:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in...

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010272/1352288), I manually installed balel loader as a dev dependency. But then when I run `yarn dev` I get this:

[image]

I go through those 4 steps, then run `yarn dev` again, and I get the first error again.

Anyone know what's going? Why isn't babel-loader being auto-installed as a dependency? (I checked in `/node_modules` and it's not there.)

Thanks very much in advance.